# Use loop in http post AngularJS asynchronous

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use foreach to get item by item and pass it to http post.

For example i want to get all chapters in lesson, i get this `[”angularjs","react","ionic"]`, and i want to pass angularjs to get all chapters in 
lessons of angualrjs .

Here is my code .

```
//  asynchronous http
         $scope.allLessons = [];
                    var init = function () {
                          var x = JSON.parse($localStorage.currentUser);
                           $http({
                           method: 'POST',
                           url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/checkLs',
                           data:  {email: x.email}
                           }).success(function (data) {
                               $scope.isRole.push(data);
                               console.log($scope.allLessons);
                               $scope.isRole.forEach(rr){
                                   $http({
                                       method: 'POST',
                                       url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/hpers',

                                       data: {
                                            name: rr
                                       },
                                   }).success(function (data) {
                                       console.log(data);
                                   }).error(function (data) {
                                       console.log(data);
                                   });
                               };

                           }).error(function (data) {
                               console.log(data);
                           });
                    };
                    init();
```

So in first http i get array of lessons `[”angularjs","react"....]`. and in second i get an error.

My backend get just name of lesson string not array, so how can i pass lesson by lesson for get the chapters of the lesson that i want ?

How and why is the best why to do it asynchronous ? and thanks.

Comment: In forEach you need to pass callback(function to execute for each element) i.e  $scope.isRole.forEach(function(rr){})

Comment: Is there any reason you are passing to an array the results coming from the first post request?

Comment: @SimoEndre yeh because i get an array of lessons and i want to pass it to view, and for each lesson i want to get her chapters .

Comment: I understand you are getting an array of lessons, but you are pushing this array of lessons into another array, which is `$scope.isRole`, then you are iterating over this array, which has no sense since you are getting only one array of lessons at once. Why you are not calling the second POST request with the date obtained from the first one? If it won't work then you might try with `promise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing it synchronously , you can do something like below.

```
//post requests 
    var Requests = [
      {
      url:"your url1",
      data:"your data"
      },
      {
      url:"your url2",
      data:"your data"
      },
      ];

  if (Requests.length>0) {
     var exit = false;
     var len = Requests.length-1;
     executePost(0, Requests, len);
  }

     var executePost = function (i, Requests, len)
        {
          if (Requests[i]!=undefined && (i<=len)) 
           {
             var request = Requests[i];
             var url = request.url;
             var data = request.data;
             $http.post(url, data, { headers: { "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8" } })
             .then(function (success) 
               {
                 console.log("Processed  " + (i + 1));              //processed log
//you can store the data to any variable here

                   if ((i + 1) <= len) {
                       executePost(i + 1, Requests, len);
                   }
               },
              function (error) 
               {
                console.log("Unsuccessfull  " + (i + 1)); 
              });
          }
       }
```

Here the function `executePost` having three parameters is called recursively.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.isRole.forEach(function(rr){
   $http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/hpers',

       data: {
            name: rr
       },
   }).success(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   }).error(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use async waterfall in async.js. It is used to work on asynchronous call.

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall

```
async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/checkLs',
                data: { email: x.email }
            }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.isRole.push(data);
                console.log($scope.allLessons);
                callback(null, isRole);
            });
        },
        function(isRole, callback) {
            // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
            isRole.forEach(rr) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/hrm/public/hpers',

                    data: {
                        name: rr
                    },
                }).success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    callback(null, data);
                }).error(function(data) {
                    callback(err, null);
                });
            };
        }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
        // result now equals 'done'
    });
```